# Problem instantiating Tab page Child Viewmodel with Prism NavigationService

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

We have managed to wire a child content page of a tab page to its own viewmodel in our Prism Xamarin Forms app. This works if ContactsScreenViewModel has a parameterless constructor. If we inject the NavigationService into the constructor the code doesn't compile.  Does anyone know how we can solve this problem?

Visual Studio is reporting that a parameterless constructor is required

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
     <TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TabsTest.Views"
            xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TabsTest.ViewModels"
            x:Class="TabsTest.Views.MainPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
              UnselectedTabColor ="Gray"
            SelectedTabColor="Green"
             BarBackgroundColor="LightGray">


    <views:ContactsScreen BackgroundColor="White" Title="Contacts">
        <views:ContactsScreen.BindingContext>
            <viewmodels:ContactsScreenViewModel/>
        </views:ContactsScreen.BindingContext>
        
        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
            <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary"
                 Priority="1" >

            </ToolbarItem>
            <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary"
                 Priority="0" >

            </ToolbarItem>
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

       </views:ContactsScreen>
    </TabbedPage>




    using Prism.Navigation;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    namespace TabsTest.ViewModels
    {
       public class ContactsScreenViewModel
       {
        private INavigationService _navigationService { get; }

        public ContactsScreenViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<viewmodels:ContactsScreenViewModel/>` is a constructor call... where do you expect the parameters to come from?

You want to either resolve the view model first (through a factory) and then attach the view to it, or make use of the `ViewModelLocator` to resolve the view model for you (and resolve and inject its dependencies) as described [here](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/Getting-Started.html), for example.

```
<TabbedPage [...] 
            xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
            prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True">
```

will resolve an instance of `TabbedPageViewModel` and put it the `BindingContext`.

That one should expose an instance of `ContactsScreenViewModel` through a property:

```
<views:ContactsScreen BindingContext={Binding ThePropertyOnTabbedPageViewModel}/>
```

You create that instance to your liking, with all parameters and dependencies you need.

Comment: Followed it all upto "You create that instance to your liking, with all parameters and dependencies you need." We wanted to avoid 'new ContactsScreenViewModel()'  within the TabbedPageViewModel

Comment: If you use dependency injection and inversion of control, it's good to avoid `new`. You want `_contactsScreenViewModelFactory.Create()` instead. If not, there's nothing wrong with `new`-ing a view model. Using some magic to make the views create their view models themselves has its use cases, but they are rare. For most of your views, you try to avoid it.